# ACAccountCredential and Facebook 3.1 SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am working with Facebook 3.1 SDK. Basically I am looking for, Facebook login using Facebook 3.2 SDK and saving credentials via `ACAccountCredential`.

However Facebook SDK still does not seem to support required OAuth Key. So the OAuthToken generation goes wrong and I get error `ACErrorAccountAuthenticationFailed`.

Do let me know, if I am missing anything to achieve this.